# Casting to String in Flutter (Why doesn't it work? Plausibly syntax-errors)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Okay, I'm certain this is stupid simple, but google is not being kind to me today, lol.

So I've tried every variant of a method to cast a firebase IdTokenResult into a string, as it's required for the program I'm writing, and nothing seems to work.  They are all giving me compiler errors, or run-time errors and not proceeding.

Exampled of things I've tried

```
String result = tokenResult as String;  // Run-Time error, wrong sub-type

String result = tokenResult.toString(); // Build-error, can't be assigned to a variable of type...
```

and everything I find about the "cast()" command only talks about lists, and doesn't let me actually convert this value into a string.

I can PRINT it as a string to the console, but that doesn't really help me in any way shape or form.  So...  How the heck can I do this?

Comment: What is the tokenResult type ? you sure you don't want the `tokenResult.token` ?

Comment: As mentioned it is the type IdTokenResult.  That's is a variable-type that is specific to firebase authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thinkg you are using this `getIdTokenResult(forceRefresh?: boolean): Promise<IdTokenResult>` which returns `IdTokenResult` so thats why it giving you run time error, you need to take `token` property from the `tokenResult` which is of String dataType  `String result = tokenResult.token;`

Comment: Ah, yes.  I knew I was doing something stupidly simple wrong, but couldn't find it anywhere on google.  Much appreciated!